# Aligning x axis with bars matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib. I have tried to make a simple bar chart, however I can't seem to get the axis to align with the bars. I have tried multiple combinations of widths however I'm sure I am missing something.

```
labels, values = zip(*charfarm.items())
indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.8
plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
plt.xticks(indexes + width, labels)
plt.show()
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahsTp.png)

Comment: Why would you add the width to the tick positions? Remove that part and it should look just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ticks are offset because of your `indexes + width` operation in your `plt.xticks` function.

Please refer the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('ggplot')

labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
values = [10, 15, 12, 9, 7, 13]

indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.8
plt.bar(indexes, values, width=width, color='green')
plt.title('Bar Chart')
plt.xticks(indexes, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]